# How did vor- compound with Schlag to signify "suggestion"?

Tags: etymology

[Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vorschlag) asseverates that the etymology of Vorschlag is "*[vor-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vor-#German)* +‎ *[Schlag](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schlag#German)*". But Schlag feels too forthright, tigerish, violent to signify "suggestion"!

I'm unpersuaded by [The meaning of "vorschlagen" | German is easy!](https://yourdailygerman.com/meaning-vorschlagen/), partly because it doesn't cite any evidence.

> Anyway, now let’s get to ***vorschlagen*** and I am sure some of you know that ***schlagen*** is the German word for ***to beat, to punch***.
> So yes… the German word for to suggest basically is *“to slap in front”*. Like… boom, here’s my idea. Think of a Germanic tribesman slamming his horn of beer on the table *“Folks… let’s do some calligraphy!”*
> Meh… not sure if that’s what they’d suggested, but you get the idea :)

> [...]

> It is not important what you suggest, even if it’s a massage with feather to your crush… in German, you’ll “smash it in front” of them.

Comment: Would it be possible to translate the last sentence because there are multiple meanings in German for feather (for instance as a historic fencing sports instrument) and crush (a blow, or a flock, ...) and I am not sure which way to interpret it.

Comment: @a_donda: "Egal was du vorschlägst, selbst deinem Schwarm eine Massage mit einer Feder ... auf deutsch 'schlägst du es vor' sie." Und wenn du so richtig über beide Ohren verliebt ist, dann hast du im Englischen eine "Quetschung".

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. Didn't know that one an thought 'massage' was a spelling error of 'message' :-)

Comment: When I first heard the term *Schlager* music, my first thought was "Hmm, sounds violent." But it really just translates to "hit music". In general, etymologies tend to make less sense the further back in time the word was coined; meanings drift, figurative meanings become primary meanings, etc. In this case we're talking about a word coined in the 8th century in language that would be unintelligible to modern German speakers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Besides *vor-*, which is an amalgam of at least five different pre-forms, there was also a root *pers-, which one might expect to have contributed here. I mean, I have no idea, but am concerned with the problem that a rather frequent verb such as *schlagen* "to beat, win,..." is known to have no certain etymology. You knew, right, that's why you are asking? This would leave the question what *-(h)lagen* would be.

1. *klagen*, as though "to claim". Although this is rather negatively connotated with suffering and complaint because of the legal field, which might be well old in this respect.

   - *Ankläger* is possibly the original etymon to *an-klagen*, if *An-* rather belongs with *ander-* (that still meant "second" with Luther, similar for En. *other*), the same way that we call Zeugen *(unbeteiligte) Dritte*. I am not sure if there are cognates with the preposition for this particular motion.
   - *Problem* might offer semantic parallels. Its Gk. stem *balle-* "throw" should belong with *Qual* "torture" according to official sources, both words from a Proto-Indo-European root assuming a sense "to punish". A *Problem* or *Vor-wurf* is not synonym with *Vorschlag*, so it explains very little, but the coincidence is still funny though. (PS: as vor *Vorwurf*, despite the apparent stem, consider a semantic tangent to PIE *wer- which reflects in words for oaths and speech; well, same for *b.lH- and *ballein*)
2. *legen, lage, Vorlage*. (PS: s.a. *überlegen*, *Überlegung*) I wont grasp the full extent of the jam, but this works various ways. First, there can be no argument that *Vor-lage*, a noun that exists, would preclude a doublette, since it could be a more recent formation. Although I have to admit between this and that, it doesn't matter much to what end the s has sprouted. As English *slay* would suggest, there never was a *c* /k/.

   - in Football, *Vorlage* is an assist, a pass from the left field for somebody else to finish.
   - in Design, it is a template, a passpartout from the left field for somebody to finish, a sample, a form, cp. *project, projectile*
   - in accademia, it is a standard work, a right of passage from the left field for somebody else to finish, I guess. I mean, the participle *vorgelegt* is met very often in book reviews, and I'm not sure if it always used with such a specific meaning, or rather colloquially to mean "submitted" (in which case it would mean the reviewer didn't have to pay for it)
   - in general, the preposition can modify the verb in the spatial as well as the temporal domain, although we have other verbs for similar senses, like *lagern*, *vorverlagern* (compare *Verschlag*, too).
   - conversely, the verb *nachlegen* is similar to *nachschlagen*. In general, both mean to repeat, do the same, although the specific meanings differ slightly. The basic semantics seem to pertain to ovens, for example--put in more fire, get more heat, so *nachlegen* in general means *to double down, reload, retry, attempt*.
   - In research, *nachschlagen* means, well, *re-search* in particular, and it seems to riff on the idea of search by *slamming* books open, up and down, and finally shut. Here too we can refer to *legen* as of a lever, *einen Hebel umlegen*, as of a book page (theoretically). At this point a fossilized infix morpheme -s- of a gone casus as in *-wards* would be imaginable. Jedenfalls ...
   - on the other hand besides the literal sense it may also mean *to develop in the same direction*<sup>[''can this be sourced?'']</sup>. Logically, the response to a *Vorschlag* should be a *Nachschlag*, if *vor* and *nach* are opposites. They are not exact opposites, but both constructions exist and should show parallels in similar domains. This abstraction may be figurative from the sense "to throw", cp. *Schlagball* as a sport, see above *problem*. This is also the most plausible explanation for *Einschlag* "characteristic", *einschlägig* "typical" (PS: notwithstanding what type of verb the original context would have required).
   - to stick with *legen*: we might note that earliest attestations with Grimm trace *einschlagen* to a sense of staking out a pillar so as to start a mine, set up shop, which is reasonably similar to *anlegen*, also compare *Anlage* "attachment* and *einschlagen* "include, envelope" (e.g. figuratively in a testament, cf. Grimm). There's more, I'm sure.
3. *lean*, *leaning*, *inclination* (from *'kel-, *' kley-) has cognates that overlap in meaning with some of the above. The velar (*'k) is typically lost to aspiration (cp. e.g. house*, Lat. *casa*; *(h)raven*, *crow*) but persists in affrication with any arbitray leading *s-*, cp. *Schlüssel, Schluss*, Lat. *clavis* (*claviatur* = *key-board*), *cludo*, En. *close* (from *(s)kleHw-), further *lock*, Ger. *Losung* "keyword, passphrase; motto" (probably belongs here, too). I have no idea how this should connect to *vorschlagen*, other than *to stand out, step forward*. (PS: An exact opposite meaning might be with secret keeping, *occult*, see *Verschlag, unterschlagen*).
4. It could of course be from the very *schlagen* similar to Two above, potentially hiding a sibilant in the vor-syllable. English cognates seem to be confined to violent meanings, *slay* and *slaughter* and a tentative root is proposed based on this which has little external evidence, while *slack* (viz. *flat*, cp. *layer*) might or might not belong here.

You know, I really doubt *problem* came from throw (go balistic), and am rather looking at *blame*, *blemish*, or so, which might be however later derivatives.

- Another note deserves, *probe, prove*, like *try, trial* (the later two surprisingly not as closely rated as I had thunk). This is directly from *pro-*, so it stands to reason that *vor-* was likewise an ablauting preverb and in this sense the head of the phrase. This leaves the tail as a possibly morphosyntactic extension akin to *-like*, *-ly*. In this view it is noticable that Kluge/Seebold make reserved mention of "Menschenschlag" or "vom gleichen Schlag" (*of the same ilk, flok*).

Finally, checking the initial idea, we find that PIE *pers- >  *pŕ̥sos > Old Norse *fors, foss* "waterfall" is not really compatible, but there are a number of other *p-r- roots with *s in the derivational morphology such as for *preḱ- +‎ *-sḱéti > *pr̥sḱétito > Ger. *forschen* cp. *fragen*, Lat. *prex, proco* (and let me say it should be curious if *procuro* did not belong here as well).

<sub>Disclaimer: All *roots have been copied from en.wiktionary--all mistakes are, as per usual, mine.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

I like an explanation from *Grimm's Wörterbuch* here:

Grimm explains one (a literal) meaning of the verb as 'to engage into a sword fight by "proposing" (and, at the same time, "smashing it in front of the attacked") a specific sword move" - *jemandem eine Tiefquart vorschlagen* - To engage into a sword fight by attacking with a specific move can be understood as a proposal on how to proceed with the fight - the attacked must react with a specific move to defend.

It's relatively easy to connect this to a figurative meaning of a general suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is one of the things where Mark Twain's treatise about the "awful German language" comes in handy.  While he had a lot of blame to place on most of German grammar, he also was enthusiastic about "-schlag" and "-zug" because those words can be combined with pretty much any possible prefix available to the German language to form a large variety of words with completely different meaning that have no obvious relation to either the prefix or, well, "Schlag" or "Zug".

There will be a contorted explanation for any of those combinations, but in the overall scheme of things, it is just a wonderful phenomenon calling for contemplation more than explanation.